# django does not load CSS file in HTML-file which extends from "base.html"

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I have a `base.html` which my `options.html` extends from like this

```html
//options.html
{% extends "webpage/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'webpage/options.css' %}">

{% block content %}
<div class="test">
    foo
</div>


{% endblock content %}
```

```html
//base.html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'webpage/base.css' %}">

    <!-- jQuery-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.slim.js" integrity="sha256-tXm+sa1uzsbFnbXt8GJqsgi2Tw+m4BLGDof6eUPjbtk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <title>:)</title>

</head>

<body>
 hello world


  {% block content %}
  {% endblock content %}


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the issue is that the CSS is not loaded/applied.

In the web-console (when I run `python manage.py runserver`) and go to the "options" page, then I can see that the `webpage/base.css` is loaded (i.e `GET /static/webpage/base.css` is printed), but the `webpage/options.css` is not.

I thought I had something wrong in the static- path, but if I move the

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'webpage/options.css' %}">` into my `base.html`(and go to my `home` page) then I see that `GET /static/webpage/options.css` is now printet and the css in there indeed takes effect.

Why can it be that it is not loaded in the `options.html` file? Note, this question is not about CSS changes not taking effect (untill hard-refresh, cache clear etc.) but it seems like the file simply isn't getting loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an HTML file extends another, it needs all its content in blocks, that it can insert into the base.html - otherwise it doesn't know where to put it.

In this case you'd want to create something like

base.html

```
<head>
...
{% block htmlhead %}
{% endblock htmlhead %}
</head>
```

And then include that block in your options.html

```
{% block htmlhead %}
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'webpage/options.css' %}">     
{% endblock htmlhead %}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Template inheritance documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance), I believe that these three paragraphs explains everything.

> All the block tag does is to tell the template engine that a child
> template may override those portions of the template.
>
> The extends tag is the key here. It tells the template engine that
> this template “extends” another template. When the template system
> evaluates this template, first it locates the parent – in this case,
> “base.html”.
>
> At that point, the template engine will notice the three block tags in
> base.html and replace those blocks with the contents of the child
> template.

So basically, when you extend a skeleton, only the parts inside the blocks are replaced, everything else is ignored.

In order to do what you want, you need another block inside your base.html header, and use it in your options.html.